# How does inserting into a Managed table in Hive affect the data in the other table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

If I have this Managed table in Hive below:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
   empId int,
   name VARCHAR(100))
COMMENT 'Employees'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Now if I insert into the above table like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Employee SELECT * FROM Employee_Test;
```

Since the `Employee` table is a Managed table, when I issue the `INSERT INTO` command above will the data from `Employee_Test` be permanently moved into the `Employee` table Directory (which in this case would be `/user/hive/warehouse` since it's a managed Table)?

Therefore, the data will not reside in `Employee_Test` anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Employee_Test` produces a set of rows (result set) that are then inserted into `Employee`.  Therefore `Employee_Test` will continue to hold those rows.  In contract `LOAD DATA INPATH...` would actually `move` the data.

Answer (score 1):

Will data from an external table be moved during a selection? No, it will not. The `INSERT FROM SELECT` query is not a "move", it's a "copy"

You're welcome to `hadoop fs -ls` the external table location to verify that.

The only way an external table's data is removed is by actually deleting the table location from disk.

> which in this case would be /user/hive/warehouse

The warehouse directory is configurable, but I believe that's the default, yes